# Bash. Para que serve export?

Tags: bash

Observando os scripts Bash, percebi que as variáveis podem ser criadas das seguintes maneiras:

`script1.sh`:

```bsh
variable1=Ola
export variable2="Ola de novo"
```

Procure saber mais sobre a diferença dessas duas maneiras de declarar as variáveis. E pelo que eu entendi export serviria para fazer variáveis globais.
Mas, rodando o script e tentando imprimir a variável global `variable2`, recebo o mesmo resultado que a variável local do meu script `` variable1````

```bsh
$ ./script1.sh 
$ echo $variable1
$
$ echo $variable2
$
```

Usando o comando `source` ou usando `.` E executando o mesmo procedimento acima, obtém como resultado a impressão das duas variáveis.

```bsh
$ source script1.sh 
$ echo $variable1
Ola
$ echo $variable2
Ola de novo
```

Neste ponto entendi que o objetivo de export não é declarar variáveis globais.
Qual é o objetivo do comando export?

Comment: Essa pergunta pode te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Answer (score 4):

Quando você define uma variável usando `export`, essa variável é copiada para os filhos do shell quando ele faz `fork`. Sem o `export`, a variável não é copiada para os filhos.

Quando você chama `./script1.sh`, o shell faz um `fork` e **o script é executado no processo filho, e não no shell onde você chamou o comando**. Portanto, a definição das variáveis é feita no processo filho, e não no shell onde você está logado. Por isso você não consegue dar `echo` nas variáveis no processo pai. O processo filho não mexe no environment do processo pai.

O programa `source` é um programa que é built-in no próprio shell, e serve para **executar um script no próprio shell, sem fazer `fork`**. Por isso que quando você chama `source script1.sh`, as variáveis aparecem no shell onde você está logado.